# UIStepper valueChanged.

Tags: ios, ibaction, sender, uistepper

I'm making an iphone app and I have met a problem..

I'm making sub views which contains labels and a UIStepper..

They are made by a for loop like so:

```
//subView to contain one ticket
    UIView *ticketTypeView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 1000, 60)];
    if(ticketCount%2){
    ticketTypeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:ticketTypeView];

    //label for ticket type name
    UILabel *ticketType = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 500, 50)];
    [ticketType setText:string];
    [ticketType setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica neue" size:20.0]];
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:ticketType];


    //UIStepper for ticket amount
    UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 16, 0, 0)];
    stepper.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:stepper];

    //label for price pr. ticket
    UILabel *pricePrTicket = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(620, 5, 100, 50)];
    [pricePrTicket setText:@"1000.00 Kr."];
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:pricePrTicket];

    //totalPrice label
    UILabel *totalTypePrice = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(900, 5, 100, 50)];
    [totalTypePrice setText:@"0.00 Kr."];
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:totalTypePrice];
```

Now.. *How do I add a IBAction valueChanged for my UIStepper?* the stepper is supposed to take the count, multiply it by the pricePrTicket and display it in the totalPrice label..

Any help or hint will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to assign unique `tag` to all your subviews of `ticketTypeView` (each should be unique) then follow @thedjnivek answer. When you get call `- (void) stepperChanged:(UIStepper*)theStepper` method, get `totalPrice` label object like this,

```
UILabel *ticketprice = (UILabel *)[theStepper.superview viewWithTag:kTagPriceTicket];
```

check if label object is not nil,

```
if(ticketprice) {
   ticketprice.text = theStepper.value * pricePrTicket;
}
```

In your for loop where you're creating `ticketTypeView` and other labels.

Your label tag should be unique for labels and the same for individual `ticketTypeView` views.

Create tags like this (you can give any integer for tags),

```
#define kTagTicketType 110
#define kTagPriceTicket 111
#define kTagTotalTypePrice 112

...
...
...

[ticketType setTag:kTagTicketType]; //NOTE this

[pricePrTicket setTag:kTagPriceTicket]; //NOTE this

[totalTypePrice setTag:kTagTotalTypePrice]; //NOTE this
```

Write above lines before adding each of the label.

Comment: how can i make unique tags in runtime and retreive those ?

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm, check my updated answer now, and let me know if you still find any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the target with `addTarget:action:` like this :

```
[stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void) stepperChanged:(UIStepper*)theStepper{
    //This method would be called on UIControlEventsValueChanged
}
```

I hope that can help you ;)